# How to click button in pop up window using python-selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, popup

I'm working to automate web page where i'm unable to close the pop up. I have tried to refresh/switch to pop up window, nothing worked.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.libertymutual.com/get-a-quote')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="1555468516747"]/section/div[2]/section/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="zipcode-1555468516747-1555468516747"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="zipcode-1555468516747-1555468516747"]').send_keys('03878')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="1555468516747"]/section/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/button').submit()
time.sleep(5)
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="discount-marketing-modal"]/header/button/svg').click()
driver.refresh()
```

If you want directly go to web page, `https://buy.libertymutual.com/auto?city=Somersworth&jurisdiction=NH&lob=Auto&policyType=Auto&zipCode=03878`

Comment: check the answer and let me know if doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace last 3 lines of your code by below lines.Used action chain to click.

```
time.sleep(5)
ok =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="discount-marketing-modal"]/footer/button')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ok).pause(1).click(ok).perform()
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="discount-marketing-modal"]/header/button/svg').click()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is css selector for popup close button : `.lm-Icon.lm-Icon-Close`

But this element can't use the `.click()` method, the `.click()` method will produce this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
```

Use `ActionChains` to solve this problem.

You can try the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.libertymutual.com/get-a-quote')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
auto_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='quotingText']//span[contains(text(), 'Auto')]")))
auto_element.click()
zip_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.zipcode")))
zip_code.click()
zip_code.send_keys("03878")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.buttonWrapper button').submit()
popup_close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lm-Icon.lm-Icon-Close")))
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(popup_close_btn).click(popup_close_btn).perform()
```

`WebDriverWait` better than `time.sleep(..)`